# How to create an exception when using radio button

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to make an exception to my radio buttons, so when a user refuses or forgets to pick an option, an error message will then be displayed. For an example; this is what I have done so far.

```
<?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $question1 = $_POST['question1'];
                $question2 = $_POST['question2'];
                $question3 = $_POST['question3'];
                $question4 = $_POST['question4'];
                $question5 = $_POST['question5'];
                $question6 = $_POST['question6'];

                if($question1== null){
                    die (print '<script> alert ("Please select one answer in Question 1."); window.location="ict.php"; </script>');
                }
                if($question2== null){
                    die (print '<script> alert ("Please select one answer in Question 2."); window.location="ict.php"; </script>');
                }
                if($question3== null){
                    die (print '<script> alert ("Please select one answer in Question 3."); window.location="ict.php"; </script>');
                }
                if($question4== null){
                    die (print '<script> alert ("Please select one answer in Question 4."); window.location="ict.php"; </script>');
                }
                if($question5== null){
                    die (print '<script> alert ("Please select one answer in Question 5."); window.location="ict.php"; </script>');
                }
                if($question6== null){
                    die (print '<script> alert ("Please select one answer in Question 6."); window.location="ict.php"; </script>');
                }


                }

?>
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Please provide more information on when you expect the alert to pop up (is this the php-script parsing the result or do you expect to generate the script-parts while user has the page open?).

Comment: what is the best way to do this because what I have display above isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You have roughly two options:

1. The form is sent to the server and the result page shows up your error message
2. The error message pops up *before* the form is sent to the server

If you follow option 1, you simply echo out the error message in the script parsing the form data (the one you wrote in the `action`-attribute of your form).

If you follow option 2, you have to use JavaScript to check the form contents when the submit button is clicked (and return `false` from that function to prohibit the form from being sent). This option will be easy to work around by the user by simply disabling JavaScript.

To get best user experience you should implement both, 1. for your users and 2. for you.